# While starting fabric server ./startFabric.s showing error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Docker and all is already updated in my pc ./downloadFabric.sh also downloaded with no errors. But ./startFabric showing following error

Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
sleeping for 15 seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up
Error response from daemon: Container 9faafbe009a4c57f0a4383e126ced758900f2d15e62e0e662ab2e3c67df3d474 is not running I even did docker start 9faafbe009a4c57f0a4383e126ced758900f2d15e62e0e662ab2e3c67df3d474 .

But it did not help. Can you help me figure this out?

[image]

Comment: This is an ancient version of Fabric, any reason for using v1.1 instead of our current v1.4.4 release

Comment: If your dead set on v1.1 for whatever reason, whats in the logs `docker logs <container id that failed>`